# Why numeric field become TWideStringField after union two datasets in SQLite using TFDQuery

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-10-seattle, firedac

I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle and below is sample codes.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient,
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf,
  FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
  FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef,
  FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf,
  FireDAC.DApt, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait, FireDAC.Comp.UI, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
  FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteVDataSet, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    ClientDataSet2: TClientDataSet;
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
    FDLocalSQL1: TFDLocalSQL;
    FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
    FDGUIxWaitCursor1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.AfterConstruction;
var o: TFDLocalSQLDataSet;
begin
  inherited;
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Code', ftString, 20);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Amount', ftFMTBcd, 2);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Find('Amount').Precision := 18;
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataSet1.AppendRecord(['A', 10]);
  ClientDataSet1.AppendRecord(['B', 20]);
  ClientDataSet1.AppendRecord(['C', 30]);

  ClientDataSet2.FieldDefs.Add('Code', ftString, 20);
  ClientDataSet2.FieldDefs.Add('Amount', ftFMTBcd, 2);
  ClientDataSet2.FieldDefs.Find('Amount').Precision := 18;
  ClientDataSet2.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataSet2.AppendRecord(['X', 10]);
  ClientDataSet2.AppendRecord(['B', 20]);
  ClientDataSet2.AppendRecord(['Y', 30]);

  o := FDLocalSQL1.DataSets.Add;
  o.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;
  o := FDLocalSQL1.DataSets.Add;
  o.DataSet := ClientDataSet2;
  FDLocalSQL1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDQuery1.Active then
    FDQuery1.Close;

  FDQuery1.Open(
    'SELECT * FROM ClientDataSet1 ' +
    'UNION ' +
    'SELECT * FROM ClientDataSet2'
  );
  ShowMessage(FDQuery1.FindField('Amount').ClassName);
end;

end.
```

Both instance of TClientDataSet have same fields structure (Code is string field, Amount is FMTBcd field).

Why FDQuery1.FindField('Amount') return TWideStringField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your q presupposes that your Amount field was numeric in the first place, but I don't think that's how Sqlite actually works.

Sqlite columns are not strictly typed, and FireDAC is telling you what all Sqlite columns really are, namely WideStrings, even if you declare columns to be of some other type. In Sqlite, defining a column to be of a particular type (f.i. auto-incrementing integer) is more a question of how data in that column behaves rather than how it is stored.

Fwiw, FireDAC in general seems to do a better job of making sense of Sqlite columns and their metadata than DBExpress does, but you still get "funnies" like the one you're asking about.

Apparently (see comment below from an authoritative sorce) if SqlLite supplies a column type name to FireDAC, then FireDAC will try to use the actual data type of the first value which occurs in the column.  If it is Null, FireDAC will use ftWideString as the column type.

Comment: Mostly correct, but one addition. If SQLite does provide to FireDAC a column type name, like in case of UNION, then FireDAC will try to use actual data type of column first value. If it is NULL, then FireDAC will define column as ftWideString.